# Как реализовать комманду mute discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я пишу бота на python и хочу реализовать для него комманду **mute**, видел варианты с добовлением роли пользывателю, но они не работают(ставил роль без прав даже выше адимина и всеровно мог писать в чат). Также сделал такой код:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['замуть', 'mute'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def мут(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amout: str = None, *, reason = None):
    await member.edit(mute = True)

    now = datetime.now()
    emb = discord.Embed()

    hour = now.hour
    minute = now.minute
    second = now.second

    emb.set_author(name=member, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    emb.add_field(name='МУТ', value=f'{hour}:{minute}:{second}')
    emb.set_footer(text=f'Был замутен администратором {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Но он просто выключает **МИКРОФОН** от имени сервера, а мне надо чтобы ты ещё и не мог писать, а не только говрить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создавая роль мьют, нужно в каждой категории(НЕ КАНАЛЕ, А КАТЕГОРИИ В КОТОРЫХ КАНАЛЫ) запретить данной роли то, что вы хотите заблокировать для замьюченых.

лично я использую такой код:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(тут id ролей админов/модеров )
async def мут(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int,*, reason):
    role = user.guild.get_role(id мьют роли) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    emb = discord.Embed( title = '✅Получилось', description=f"Пользователю {user} выдали мут!\nВремя пробывания в муте: {time} минут\nПричина выдачи мута: {reason}!", colour = discord.Color.green())
    emb.set_footer(text = 'Действие выполнено модератором/админом - ' + ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)
    await user.add_roles(role) #выдает мьют роль
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60) #ждет нужное кол-во секунд умноженных на 60(вы выдаете мут на минуты. Допустим time = 10, то вы выдали мут на 10 минут)
    await user.remove_roles(role) #снимает мьют роль
```

он выдает роль мьюта на определенное кол-во минут

но если вы хотите свой код, то я его дописал(тоже на выдачу роли)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['замуть', 'mute'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def мут(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: int, *, reason = None):
    role = user.guild.get_role(id мьют роли) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    emb = discord.Embed()
    emb.set_author(name=member, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text=f'Был замутен администратором {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60) #ждет нужное кол-во секунд умноженных на 60(вы выдаете мут на минуты. Допустим time = 10, то вы выдали мут на 10 минут)
    await user.remove_roles(role) #снимает мьют роль
```

извините, но убрал часть с datetime.

А, ну и если вам скучно можете получить список всех каналов(голосовых и текстовых) и для текстовых запретить то, что вам нужно и для голосовых.
Но это грубо говоря вы в замен выдачи роли с такими-же правами усложняете работу и запрещаете пользователь что-то делать без выдачи роли.